# Cannot display image to JLabel from JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jlabel, jfilechooser

### Code

```
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
    JFileChooser fileChooser=new JFileChooser(); 

    int a=fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);  
    if(a==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)  {

    FilefileToOpen=fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    BufferedImage bi;

    try {
    bi = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\nexboy94\\Desktop\\IT 2297- Object-Oriented Analysis and Design Project\\Refresh.png"));

    lblNewLabel_UploadResidentImageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bi));
    } catch (IOException e2) {
    e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    }
```

### Error is this

```
   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
   at ui.CreateResident$8.actionPerformed(CreateResident.java:260)
   at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
   at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
   at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
   at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
   at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
   at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: did you try putting the directory inside the imageicon's parenthesis instead of reading it in imageio first ?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  My 'best guess' is that the code declares bu does not create the label. 2) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Comment: can tell the solution to this? Is bi= path name?

Comment: line 260 is bi= ImageIO.read(new File("");

Comment: *"can tell the solution to this?"*  Can provide an SSCCE?  Tip:  Add @CME64 (or whoever - the `@` is important) to *notify* them of a new comment.